# Use different arguments based on different files?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have the following 2 functions with different arguments

```
import argparse

def get_train_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('data_dir')
    parser.add_argument('--save_dir', type = str, default = 'checkpoints/', help = 'Save checkpoint directory')
    parser.add_argument('--arch', nargs='?', type = str, const = 'VGG', default = 'VGG', help = 'Select architecture. Choose VGG or AlexNet', choices=['VGG', 'AlexNet'])
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type = float, default = '0.001', help = 'Select the model learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--hidden_units', type = int, default = '1024', help = 'Select the model hidden units')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type = int, default = '2', help = 'Select the number of epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu', nargs='?', type = str, const = 'gpu', default = 'gpu', help = 'Use GPU for training')

    return parser.parse_args()

def get_predict_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('single_image', nargs='?', const = 'flowers/test/1/image_06743.jpg')
    parser.add_argument('checkpoint')
    parser.add_argument('--top_k', type = int, default = '5', help = 'Select number of top propabilities')
    parser.add_argument('--category_names', nargs='?', type = dict, const = cat_to_name.json, default = cat_to_name.json, help = 'Select the model learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu', nargs='?', type = str, const = 'gpu', default = 'gpu', help = 'Use GPU for inference')

    return parser.parse_args()
```

My problem is that when I try to run

> python predict.py single_image checkpoint

I get

```
usage: predict.py [-h] [--save_dir SAVE_DIR] [--arch [{VGG,AlexNet}]]
                  [--learning_rate LEARNING_RATE]
                  [--hidden_units HIDDEN_UNITS] [--epochs EPOCHS]
                  [--gpu [GPU]]
                  data_dir
predict.py: error: unrecognized arguments: checkpoint
```

in `train.py` I use

> from get_input_args import get_train_args

to run `get_train_args()`

in `predict.py` i have

```
from get_input_args import get_predict_args
from load_checkpoint import load_checkpoint
from train import cp_path

predict_arg = get_predict_args()

if predict_arg.gpu:
    device = 'cuda'
else:
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print('device:', device)

# Load checkpoint from saved path
load_checkpoint(cp_path, device)
```

What is the best way to organize my code so that each set of arguments are available based on the file that is run in the terminal?

Comment: The error looks like `predict.py`  ran `get_train_args`.  How or why that happened is hard to say, since you just provided a piece of the `predict.py` code.

Comment: @hpaulj I updated the OP with the code in `predict.py`

Answer (score 0):

In `predict.py`, I was using

> from train.py import cp_path

This was causing `train.py` to run first, before importing the `predict.py` arguments.